# Alamofire put with array of ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have array of `ObjectMapper`:

```
var arr = [Model]
```

now how can i use `Alamofire` to send this array to server with `.PUT` or `.POST` method?

```
Alamofire.request(.PUT, Config().apiGroup, parameters: arr, encoding: .JSON)
```

it says that parameters type is `[String : AnyObject]?`.

I tried with this too:

```
var params = Array<AnyObject>()
for entry in arr {
    params.append(Mapper().toJSON(entry))
}
```

and then to pass `params` to `parameters`, but still getting error.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to convert:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let pjson = attendences.toJSONString(prettyPrint: false)
    let data = (pjson?.data(using: .utf8))! as Data

    request.httpBody = data

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in


        print(response)

    }
```